# Getting full project path java

Tags: java

In my project i have forder with database. When i move project to another directory my database url doesn't work. So, I want to create universal method for getting current project path for creating universal database url.
I'm looking for a way to get path like this:

```
C:\Users\UserName\FolderName\ProjectName
```

Structure of my project:
[Structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ATm.png)

[image]

Comment: After `ProjectName` there is several architecture possible, simple/maven/... so diffcult

Comment: ya @Lutzi, is right , but it should be done in different way ` <context-param>
    <param-name>upload.path</param-name>
    <param-value>/home/../pathtothefile</param-value>
  </context-param>` in web.xml and get the context path upload.path

Answer (score 1):

Generally, tying your database location to the location of your application, which typically ends up in a JAR, is not a good idea. Instead, figure out where you want to put your database and add a reference. If necessary, you can pass the location from the command line or from a PROPERTIES file. Note that the PROPERTIES approach runs into problems if you package your application in a JAR, as you then can't modify it.